# Rewrite the php code?

Tags: php

How can I rewrite this code:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");  
$timech = mysql_result($res, 0, 0); 
$timecheck = time() - $timech; 
$time = time(); 

if($timecheck > 60) { 

session_start(); 
$offline="Offline";
$session = "";
$user_time_check = "";
$user_time_check = "";  
$ipaddress = "";
mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
mysql_db_query(db_name,"UPDATE user SET server_time_check = '$server_time_check', ip_address = '$ipaddress', last_sign_in_stamp = '".time()."', online = '$offline', session = '$session'") or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_close();  

}
```

The time() on the php seems to be messing up with my code not showing pagination that also uses $res. When I use $time, the function will not update my database. Does anybody know what the issue is?

Does anybody know how I can rewrite it?

Comment: Is the value an int or a varchar in the db? And stop using mysql, it's deprecated.

Comment: You could be getting a wrong column by assuming the 0th cell of the result is what you need, especially if your query is selecting all cells. Make sure to be explicit on which column you are asking the code to retrieve for you, and also check the data type.

Comment: No the users was changed to user... I think the $res is messing it up and the time

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL & feel that the `$time` is mixing things up, better to use MySQL’s internal Unix timestamp function, [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp).  So this line:

```
mysql_db_query(db_name,"UPDATE user SET server_time_check = '$server_time_check', ip_address = '$ipaddress', last_sign_in_stamp = '".time()."', online = '$offline', session = '$session'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Changes to this:

```
mysql_db_query(db_name,"UPDATE user SET server_time_check = '$server_time_check', ip_address = '$ipaddress', last_sign_in_stamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), online = '$offline', session = '$session'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: No this is the code that is messing up everything     $timecheck = time() - $timech;